# AngularJS: Dynamically load HTML tag retrieved from database

Tags: json, angularjs, factory, ngroute

I am fetching the data from a JSON file using `factory`:

```
appService.factory('svr', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('data/:pageName.json', {}, {query:{method:'GET', isArray:true}});
}]);
```

and accessing it in `controller`:

```
appController.controller('requirementCtrl', ['$scope', 'svr', function($scope, svr){
    $scope.ques = svr.query({pageName:'question'});
}]);
```

Data in the JSON file contains the label, four options and a type checkbox like value.  I have to format it into an HTML tag using this data.

I find one way is to create an HTML tag in `controller` and bind it to `div` using `ng-bind-html`.  Directives does not work as I have implemented `ngRoute`.

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: may be you need `ng-include`.

Comment: Please show the solution you've tried and point out where it's failing.

Comment: Why would you not just set up the HTML statically in the template, and then use the results of `svr.query` to set `$scope` vars so it updates? You can even hide it with a `$scope.ready = false` (set to `true` when load is done) and use `ng-show` in the template?

Comment: I can have many checkbox so how can i use static template for variable data

Comment: `ng-repeat` and use a `$scope` var to determine how many. I assume you mean the JSON is an array of objects?

Comment: Tell you what, edit the post to add sample json and basic template

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to "compile" your element like :

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

> http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/

Other solution maybe (By Ben Nadel): http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2449-directive-link-observe-and-watch-functions-execute-inside-an-angularjs-context.htm